# Twig - is there a way to loop with decimals?

Tags: symfony, twig

I need to be able to generate the numbers 0-5 in 0.5 increments (so, 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, etc.) in my view.  Is there a way to do it out of the box with twig's `for` loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on example two in the [twig documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/range.html) You should be able to do

```
{% for i in range(0, 5, 0.5) %}
    {{ i }},
{% endfor %}
```